# Transforming JSON with Aeson for testing

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, yesod, aeson

In an integration test of a Yesod REST service, the called API returns

```json
{
  "userId": "xxx"
}
```

where `xxx` is a MongoDB ObjectID (12 byte hex-encoded string).

I would like to verify that the returned JSON is, in fact, in this form, using [aeson](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.8.0.0).

Is there a way to transform the JSON into a canonical form, say

```json
{
   "userId": "-1"
}
```

if the value of `userId` field matches a given regular expression?

I can then use `assertEquals` to match the response JSON (actual) to an expected value.

In the [Scala Lift JSON library](https://github.com/lift/lift/tree/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json) I can do something like the following:

```
val actual = json.transform {
case JField("userId", value)
  if """[0-9a-f]{24}""".r.findFirstIn(value).isDefined =>
  JField("userId", "-1")
}
```

Is there something similar in aeson?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For generic transformations of algebraic data types, have a look at the [uniplate](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/uniplate) package.

For example, given this expression type:

```
data Expr = Val Int
          | Add Expr Expr
          | Sub Expr Expr
          | Div Expr Expr
          | Mul Expr Expr
          | Neg Expr
          deriving (Show, Eq)
```

one can transform the subtree `Neg (Val x)` to `Val (negate x)` everywhere with this function:

```
import Data.Generics.Uniplate

optimise :: Expr -> Expr
optimise = transform $ \x -> case x of
    Neg (Val i) -> Val (negate i)
    x -> x
```